# Customizar correo wordpress wp_mail

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

quiero customizar el cuerpo de correo que se envia, se esta usando wordpress, para ello estoy usando el wp_mail, pero no he logrado meter html dentro del mensaje he intentado de las siguientes 2 formas pero no ha funcionado, cual seria la forma correcta de hacerlo?

```
wp_mail($correo, "miempresa.", include('clavesistema-copia.html').$nuevoPassword."");
return array(true, $lastid, 'Usuario registrado con éxito.</br>recibira su contraseña por correo');
```

aclaro es para enviar un correo al registrarse en un formulario de wordpress.

la otra forma que intente

```
wp_mail($correo, "miempresa.", ?>html aqui<?php);
return array(true, $lastid, 'Usuario registrado con éxito.</br>recibira su contraseña por correo');
```

pero sale esto syntax error, unexpected '?>'

wp_mail es donde va los campos del correo, es decir $correo es a donde se envia, "mi empresa" es quien lo envia y donde quiero colocar el html vendría siendo el cuerpo del correo.
lo que esta en el return es el mensaje de confirmación cuando se registra en el formulario

Comment: Si ese es todo tu código, está demasiado incompleto. Primero de todo, las variables no están siquiera definidas, envías los datos a la nada y no lo recibes en ningún lado. Deberías mirarte mejor el manual de PHP https://www.php.net/manual/es/index.php  para intentar desarrollar más tu código, y en caso de que te surja alguna duda después de intentarlo, volver a preguntar por el foro.

Comment: no entiendo que tiene ver la variables con meter html dentro de wp_mail, aun asi no es todo el codigo el error "unexpected '?>'" no creo que sea porque una variable no esta definida

Comment: Por favor, introduce todo el código para poder ayudarte. Solo con lo que hay puesto no es suficiente

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer del todo, pero en un mismo archivo php se puede añadir código html. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
  wp_mail($correo, "miempresa.");
  return array(true, $lastid);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <p>Usuario registrado con éxito.</br>recibira su contraseña por correo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Sería el mismo código que tuvieses en dos archivos diferentes, pero en uno solo

Comment: me sale esto syntax error, unexpected '?>'

Comment: No sé qué hiciste, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta añadiendo eso nuevo?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta

Comment: No sé si es el único código que tienes, pero fíjate ahora en la respuesta. Se haría así, como ejemplo

Comment: ya edite la pregunta a ver si me entiendes mejor